# mailing a web page

Tags: html

I have a web page that I created with html tags(form and table) and I used inline style sheeting to style the page. 
What is the html that I would use to send the whole page to an e-mail address so that the person receives a link of the page to open as an e-mail.

Comment: You cannot link someone to a page to have them open it as an email... you have to email it to them.

Comment: You want to send the html document as an email?  Are you using an email client (e.g. Outlook, Outlook Express, Thunderbird) or web-based email (i.e. you go online with a browser to send emails)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't just send links in your emails because you are likely to be considered a spammer. If you want to send emails with HTML content then just send them as HTML emails. If you need help with preparing the page to fit the HTMl email requirements use a CSS inliner tool like [**this one**](http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css).

Answer (score 1):

You have the possibility of creating an Mail me! link, which utilises the mailto protocol recognised by all major browsers, however spam bots will find this link as well.

If you want to keep the form, which I assume from your question, you would have to introduce a serverside language to process and mail the form. **php** could do the trick using its `mail` function. `asp` or other server side languages could do the trick as well but I'm not familiar with those languages.

If you google for *php submit form to email* you will probably get a few hundred results explaining how to do this.